Voting irregularities
I noted that a user has been suspended for voting irregularities.
What does it mean and why it happened?
Moreover, seen his reputation growth and skill (at least, I saw him to answer to pretty complicated questions) is that a pity he's been suspended?

I won't comment on individual cases but can say what it means and what happens.
Some users cheat by up- or downvoting questions and answers without regard for merit. This is unfair to other users and therefore forbidden. Automatic systems are in place to detect this behavior and to inform the moderators. When we see a warning and think it's correct we escalate to the Stack Exchange team who will do further checks and take action if necessary. These actions include:

Merging of accounts by the same user invalidating their votes 
Deletion of offending accounts
Invalidating of votes of an account if only the voting behavior is wrong
Suspension of an account and the issuing of a warning 


Of course, I did not refer to the user particularly, but I wanted to understand what happened. Anyway, thanks for the answer Bob!
